# subtracting two times from one another?

Tags: php

Stuck on this question for college!

subtract one time from another. The times are in the format “HH:MM:SS:FF” where:

```
HH = hours – there are 24 hours in a day
MM = minutes – there are 60 minutes in a hour
SS = seconds – there are 60 seconds in a minute
FF = frames – there are 25 frames in a second
```

The time is always 11 characters long and each element will always be 2 characters – padded with zeros if required.

```
 subtract $y from $x

'$x = “03:14:59:20”;
 $y = “01:16:01:02”;
```

I have done this code

```
<?php
$now = new DateTime(); // current date/time
$now = new DateTime("03:14:59:20");
$ref = new DateTime("01:16:01:02");
$diff = $now->diff($ref);
printf('%d hours, %d minutes %d seconds %d frames', $diff->h, $diff->i, $diff->s, $diff->f);
```

but the frames part does not work
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't include frames in the time -- PHP's DateTime class doesn't know about frames.

Comment: How would I get around this?

Comment: Convert the times to seconds, multiply by 25, and add the frames to this. Then subtract this to get the difference in frames.

Comment: still using the DateTime function or starting from scratch? could you show me how to do this ?

Comment: You can `explode` it by `:` concat the first 3 results into respective `x and y strings` then you are left with the frames, subtract them and concat that to get your final answer. Actually, this might not work if `frames1 - frames2 < 0`.)